# Bootstrap Tabs Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was tried to animate bootstrap tabs by adding css class but it's not working, the simple idea is animate tabs content based on bootstrap class .active, the problem that the transition not working:

```css
.tab-content .tab-pane h3 {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.tab-content .active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="exTab1" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
      <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
      <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
      <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
      <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use transition between `display:block` and `display:none`, you will need to set `display:block` to `.tab-content>.tab-pane`.

```
 #exTab1 .tab-content {
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 #exTab1>.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<style>
  .tab-content .tab-pane h3 {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
    transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .tab-content .active h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  
  #exTab1 .tab-content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #exTab1>.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>

<div id="exTab1" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
      <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
      <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
      <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
      <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I know that we can't transition between display block and display none, the transition in my code based on h3 opacity and transform

Comment: and why you make position of .tabe-pane is absolute

Comment: Even if you are setting transition to `h3` but still you will need to use `display:block` to parent, because transition is depending on `.active` which is a parent class, and after adding `display:block` elements are creating vertical space, that's why I added position absolute.

Comment: Thank you very much